# MongoDB count() query returns outdated result in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, robo3t

Documents in my MongoDB collection are changing status field very frequently. I can see it very clear, using a mongoDB client (Robo 3T).

Now I'd like to monitor this process using `mongo` shell:

```
mongo --host=localhost db --eval "db.getCollection('events').find({status:'ACTIVE'}).count()"
```

This returns a correct result, but then mongoDB "caches" it and would not return an updated result for another ~ 10 seconds. I need to have an update every 200 ms.

The same query from Robo 3T always returns an updated result, in ~5ms.

From my observation, when the load is lower, mongo shell count updates are coming on every request.

I can't find any cache-like mechanism information in MongoDB documentation. How can I disable it? Why does it work ok from Robo 3T?

P.S

I observed the same behavior with a python script, which is polling mongo with count() query - the results are cached. But once I start execute a query in Robo 3T, the numbers start moving in python and mongo shell! What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itcount()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.itcount/) which actually executes the query on an existing iterator.

```
mongo --host=localhost db \
    --eval "db.getCollection('events').find({status:'ACTIVE'}).itcount()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to remove all the cached query plans for a collection:

```
db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()
```

if you don’t change the where condition, updates will be cached.

Doc: [Plan cache](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-plan-cache/)

Comment: Behavior is the same. I think it is expected, since this command invalidates the query plan, but it is ok the plan to be the same. Values are constantly changing, and they will be different even with the same plan